# Image not rendering correctly in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I recently switched from MVC2 to MVC3 and my images are no longer rendering correctly on the development server.

Here is the code:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("/content/images/sign_up.png")" height="50" width="550" />
```

Please note I use 'img' instead of 'image in the actual code but I could not post that.

When I look at the rendered HTML it says

`<img src="/content/images/sign_up.png" height="50" width="550" />`

When I try the URL `localhost/content/images/sign_up.png` the image shows up correctly.

Am I doing something wrong with MVC3, or maybe I need to make an adjustment to the IIS server?

Comment: How exactly are they rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `~` sign:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/content/images/sign_up.png")" 
    height="50" width="550" />
```

From MSDN:

> `Url.Content` Converts a virtual (relative) path to an application absolute path.

But to do that, you need to tell it you're passing a virtual path, which is achieved with the `~` .

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I spent hours on something so simple. Thanks!